# PasswordReset() throws exception - passwordAnswer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an app that I'm trying to implement the following, but can't seem to figure out how:

1. User signs up, but the system creates its own temporary password for them
2. Admin approves user and as part of that approval, the user gets sent a temporary username/password.

The problem is that I can't set the MembershipProvider to enable password retrieval as that seems to disable certficate authentication.  I do have passwordReset enabled, but when I try to use it in step 2 (trying to create a new password so I can have it in plaintext to email it to the user), it throws an error:

General Error: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: passwordAnswer

Is there any way around this?

Here's a code snippet of the relevant code:

```
MembershipUser mu = Membership.GetUser(Session["UserId"], false);
string password = mu.ResetPassword();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to circumvent this issue by adding requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" to the membership provider in my web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">

      <providers>

        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            connectionStringName="DB"
            applicationName="Acme"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="15"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
            passwordAttemptWindow="3"
            passwordFormat="Hashed" />

      </providers>

    </membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

The password is null because nothing got entered. In your code, just use an `if`:

```
if (passwordAnswer==null){
//do stuff here
}
```

While you can write anything there, I recommend, maybe:

```
if (passwordAnswer==null){
 passwordAnswer=" ";//just a space
}
```

If you want it to be a generated password, research on generating random alphanumeric strings.

Comment: I just checked though and passwordAnswer is getting filled in when I create the user initially.  I'm doing MembershipCreateUser() and setting passwordAnswer to "0" but when I look in the database it's a long encrypted string, but not the same as the password column...

Comment: Ok, it looks like I was able to potentially fix this when I added requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" to the membership provider